# Python Kivy packing to exe

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, exe, pyinstaller

I am trying to packing kivy for windows. I am using windows 10 with python 3.7.2 with kivy 1.10.1. With the reference of this [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-windows.html) I have done exe building successfully but when I  run exe it shows the     following error
 
`Error loading Python DLL 'C:\Users\acer\Desktop\coding\build\hello\python37.dll'.
LoadLibrary: The specified module could not be found.`

Thanks for helping me :D
    and This is the Specs i got from `python -m PyInstaller --name hello main.py`
    hello.spec

```
    # -*- mode: python -*-

    block_cipher = None


    a = Analysis(['main.py'],
                 pathex=['C:\\Users\\acer\\Desktop\\coding'],
                 binaries=[],
                 datas=[],
                 hiddenimports=[],
                 hookspath=[],
                 runtime_hooks=[],
                 excludes=[],
                 win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
                 win_private_assemblies=False,
                 cipher=block_cipher,
                 noarchive=False)
    pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
                 cipher=block_cipher)
    exe = EXE(pyz,
              a.scripts,
              [],
              exclude_binaries=True,
              name='hello',
              debug=False,
              bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
              strip=False,
              upx=True,
              console=True )
    coll = COLLECT(exe,
                   a.binaries,
                   a.zipfiles,
                   a.datas,
                   strip=False,
                   upx=True,
                   name='hello')
```

This is mine code block

```
        import kivy
        from kivy.app import App
        from kivy.uix.label import Label
        from kivy.uix.button import Button
        from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
        from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
        from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
```

```
    import sys

    kivy.require('1.10.1')

    class Main(App):
                def build(self):
            self.UIlayout = FloatLayout(size=(300,300))

            self.textarea = TextInput(font_size=18)

            self.savebtn = Button(text="save",size_hint=(.1,.1),pos_hint={"bottom":0})
            self.exitbtn = Button(text="exit",size_hint=(.1,.1),pos_hint={"right":1})

            self.exitbtn.on_press = lambda: sys.exit(0)
            self.savebtn.on_press = self.savefile

            self.UIlayout.add_widget(self.textarea)

            self.UIlayout.add_widget(self.savebtn)
            self.UIlayout.add_widget(self.exitbtn)

           return self.UIlayout

               def savefile(self):
                    print(self.textarea.text)
                       with open("filename.py",'w') as f:
                           f.write(self.textarea.text)  
    Main().run()
```

This is warn-hello.txt

```
        This file lists modules PyInstaller was not able to find. This does not
        necessarily mean this module is required for running you program. Python and
        Python 3rd-party packages include a lot of conditional or optional module. 
        For
        example the module 'ntpath' only exists on Windows, whereas the module
    'posixpath' only exists on Posix systems.

    Types if import:
    * top-level: imported at the top-level - look at these first
    * conditional: imported within an if-statement
    * delayed: imported from within a function
    * optional: imported within a try-except-statement

    IMPORTANT: Do NOT post this list to the issue-tracker. Use it as a basis for
               yourself tracking down the missing module. Thanks!

    missing module named 'win32com.gen_py' - imported by win32com (conditional, optional), C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks    \pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py (top-level)
    missing module named pyimod03_importers - imported by C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgres.py (top-level)
    missing module named _uuid - imported by uuid (optional)
    missing module named __builtin__ - imported by PIL.Image (optional), pkg_resources._vendor.pyparsing (conditional)
    missing module named ordereddict - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.pyparsing (optional)
    missing module named 'com.sun' - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs (delayed, conditional, optional)
    missing module named com - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs (delayed)
    missing module named 'pkg_resources.extern.pyparsing' - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.packaging.markers (top-level), pkg_resources._vendor.packaging.requirements (top-level)
    missing module named StringIO - imported by pygments.util (conditional), pkg_resources._vendor.six (conditional)
    missing module named __main__ - imported by pkg_resources (delayed, optional)
    missing module named pkg_resources.extern.packaging - imported by pkg_resources.extern (top-level), pkg_resources (top-level)
    missing module named pkg_resources.extern.appdirs - imported by pkg_resources.extern (top-level), pkg_resources (top-level)
    missing module named 'pkg_resources.extern.six.moves' - imported by pkg_resources (top-level), pkg_resources._vendor.packaging.requirements (top-level)
    missing module named pkg_resources.extern.six - imported by pkg_resources.extern (top-level), pkg_resources (top-level), pkg_resources.py31compat (top-level)
    missing module named 'multiprocessing.forking' - imported by C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py (optional)
    missing module named multiprocessing.get_context - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.pool (top-level), multiprocessing.managers (top-level), multiprocessing.sharedctypes (top-level)
    missing module named multiprocessing.TimeoutError - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.pool (top-level)
    missing module named multiprocessing.BufferTooShort - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.connection (top-level)
    missing module named multiprocessing.AuthenticationError - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.connection (top-level)
    missing module named multiprocessing.set_start_method - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.spawn (top-level)
    missing module named multiprocessing.get_start_method - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.spawn (top-level)
    missing module named multiprocessing.Event - imported by multiprocessing (optional), kivy.clock (optional)
    missing module named resource - imported by posix (top-level), C:\Users\acer\Desktop\coding\main.py (top-level)
    missing module named posix - imported by os (conditional, optional), C:\Users\acer\Desktop\coding\main.py (top-level)
    missing module named _posixsubprocess - imported by subprocess (conditional), multiprocessing.util (delayed), C:\Users\acer\Desktop\coding\main.py (top-level)
    missing module named readline - imported by cmd (delayed, conditional, optional), code (delayed, conditional, optional), pdb (delayed, optional), C:\Users\acer\Desktop\coding\main.py (top-level)
    excluded module named _frozen_importlib - imported by importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional), C:\Users\acer\Desktop\coding\main.py (top-level)
    missing module named _frozen_importlib_external - imported by importlib._bootstrap (delayed), importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional), C:\Users\acer\Desktop\coding\main.py (top-level)
    missing module named _winreg - imported by platform (delayed, optional), pygame (conditional), pygame.sysfont (conditional), C:\Users\acer\Desktop\coding\main.py (top-level), pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs     (delayed, conditional), pygments.formatters.img (optional)
    missing module named _scproxy - imported by urllib.request (conditional)
    missing module named java - imported by platform (delayed), C:\Users\acer\Desktop\coding\main.py (top-level)
    missing module named 'java.lang' - imported by platform (delayed, optional), C:\Users\acer\Desktop\coding\main.py (top-level), xml.sax._exceptions (conditional)
    missing module named vms_lib - imported by platform (delayed, conditional, optional), C:\Users\acer\Desktop\coding\main.py (top-level)
    missing module named termios - imported by tty (top-level), getpass (optional), C:\Users\acer\Desktop\coding\main.py (top-level)
    missing module named urllib.FancyURLopener - imported by urllib (conditional, optional), pygments.lexers._sourcemod_builtins (conditional, optional)
    missing module named urllib.urlretrieve - imported by urllib (conditional, optional), pygments.lexers._php_builtins (conditional, optional)
    missing module named urllib.urlopen - imported by urllib (conditional, optional), pygments.lexers._lua_builtins (conditional, optional), pygments.lexers._postgres_builtins (conditional, optional)
    missing module named urllib.pathname2url - imported by urllib (conditional), kivy.core.video.video_gstplayer (conditional), kivy.core.audio.audio_gstplayer (conditional)
    missing module named grp - imported by shutil (optional), tarfile (optional), pathlib (delayed), C:\Users\acer\Desktop\coding\main.py (top-level)
    missing module named 'org.python' - imported by pickle (optional), C:\Users\acer\Desktop\coding\main.py (top-level), xml.sax (delayed, conditional)
    missing module named pwd - imported by posixpath (delayed, conditional), shutil (optional), tarfile (optional), http.server (delayed, optional), webbrowser (delayed), pathlib (delayed, conditional, optional), netrc    (delayed, conditional), getpass (delayed), C:\Users\acer\Desktop\coding\main.py (top-level), docutils.frontend (delayed, conditional, optional)
    missing module named org - imported by copy (optional), C:\Users\acer\Desktop\coding\main.py (top-level)
    missing module named ios - imported by kivy.metrics (delayed, conditional), kivy.core.window (delayed)
    missing module named android - imported by kivy.metrics (delayed, conditional), kivy.core.window (delayed, conditional), kivy.base (delayed, optional), kivy.input.providers.androidjoystick (optional),     kivy.core.clipboard.clipboard_android (top-level), kivy.support (delayed, optional), kivy.core.window.window_pygame (conditional, optional)
    missing module named jnius - imported by kivy.metrics (delayed, conditional), kivy.core.clipboard.clipboard_android (top-level), kivy.core.camera.camera_android (top-level)  
    missing module named Queue - imported by kivy.compat (optional), pygame.threads (conditional)
    missing module named ConfigParser - imported by kivy.config (optional)
    missing module named Leap - imported by kivy.input.providers.leapfinger (delayed)
    missing module named copy_reg - imported by cStringIO (top-level), pygame (conditional)
    missing module named 'pygame._view' - imported by pygame (delayed)   
    missing module named pygame.sdlmain_osx - imported by pygame (top-level), pygame.macosx (top-level)
    missing module named OpenGL - imported by pygame (delayed)
    missing module named numpy - imported by PIL.ImageFilter (optional), pygame._numpysurfarray (top-level), pygame._numpysndarray (top-level), pygame (delayed), kivy.core.camera.camera_picamera (top-    level), kivy.core.camera.camera_android (delayed)
    missing module named 'pygame.movie' - imported by pygame (optional)
    missing module named pygame.SRCALPHA - imported by pygame (top-level), pygame.ftfont (top-level)
    missing module named Py25Queue - imported by pygame.threads (conditional)
    missing module named cStringIO - imported by pygame.compat (conditional), pygments.util (conditional)
    missing module named fcntl - imported by kivy.input.providers.hidinput (conditional), kivy.input.providers.linuxwacom (conditional)
    missing module named oscpy - imported by kivy.input.providers.tuio (delayed, optional)
    missing module named olefile - imported by PIL.FpxImagePlugin (top-level), PIL.MicImagePlugin (top-level)
    missing module named Tkinter - imported by PIL.ImageTk (conditional)
    missing module named UserDict - imported by PIL.PdfParser (optional)
    missing module named 'PySide.QtCore' - imported by PIL.ImageQt (conditional, optional)
    missing module named 'PyQt4.QtCore' - imported by PIL.ImageQt (conditional, optional)
    missing module named 'PySide2.QtCore' - imported by PIL.ImageQt (conditional, optional) 
    missing module named PySide2 - imported by PIL.ImageQt (conditional, optional)    
    missing module named 'PyQt5.QtCore' - imported by PIL.ImageQt (conditional, optional)
    missing module named pathlib2 - imported by PIL.Image (optional)
    missing module named cffi - imported by PIL.Image (optional), PIL.PyAccess (top-level), PIL.ImageTk (delayed, conditional, optional)
    missing module named PIL._imagingagg - imported by PIL (delayed, conditional, optional), PIL.ImageDraw (delayed, conditional, optional)
    missing module named smb - imported by kivy.loader (delayed, conditional, optional)
    missing module named urllib2 - imported by kivy.loader (delayed, conditional)
    missing module named 'pyobjus.dylib_manager' - imported by kivy.core.audio.audio_avplayer (top-level), kivy.core.clipboard.clipboard_nspaste (optional)
    missing module named pyobjus - imported by kivy.core.audio.audio_avplayer (top-level), kivy.core.clipboard.clipboard_nspaste (optional)
    missing module named new - imported by kivy.weakmethod (conditional)
    missing module named 'ffpyplayer.tools' - imported by kivy.core.image.img_ffpyplayer (top-level), kivy.core.video.video_ffpyplayer (optional), kivy.core.audio.audio_ffpyplayer (optional)
    missing module named 'ffpyplayer.player' - imported by kivy.core.video.video_ffpyplayer (optional), kivy.core.audio.audio_ffpyplayer (optional)
    missing module named ffpyplayer - imported by kivy.core.image.img_ffpyplayer (top-level), kivy.core.video.video_ffpyplayer (optional), kivy.core.audio.audio_ffpyplayer (optional)
    missing module named dbus - imported by kivy.core.clipboard.clipboard_dbusklipper (optional)
    missing module named ffmpeg - imported by kivy.core.video.video_ffmpeg (optional)
    missing module named 'ffpyplayer.pic' - imported by kivy.core.image.img_ffpyplayer (top-level)
    missing module named pygments.formatters.BBCodeFormatter - imported by pygments.formatters (top-level), kivy.uix.codeinput (top-level)
    missing module named ctags - imported by pygments.formatters.html (optional)
    missing module named colorama - imported by pygments.cmdline (delayed, conditional, optional)
    missing module named kivy.lib.vidcore_lite.egl - imported by kivy.lib.vidcore_lite (top-level), kivy.core.window.window_egl_rpi (top-level)
    missing module named kivy.lib.vidcore_lite.bcm - imported by kivy.lib.vidcore_lite (top-level), kivy.core.window.window_egl_rpi (top-level)
    missing module named 'twisted.internet' - imported by kivy.support (delayed)
    missing module named gobject - imported by kivy.support (delayed, optional)
    missing module named gi - imported by kivy.support (delayed, optional), kivy.core.clipboard.clipboard_gtk3 (top-level)
    missing module named enchant - imported by kivy.core.spelling.spelling_enchant (top-level)
    missing module named 'gi.repository' - imported by kivy.core.clipboard.clipboard_gtk3 (top-level), kivy.core.camera.camera_gi (top-level)
    missing module named AppKit - imported by kivy.core.spelling.spelling_osxappkit (top-level)
    missing module named android_mixer - imported by kivy.core.audio.audio_pygame (conditional, optional)
    missing module named 'android.mixer' - imported by kivy.core.audio.audio_pygame (conditional, optional)
    missing module named cv2 - imported by kivy.core.camera.camera_opencv (optional), kivy.core.camera.camera_android (delayed)
    missing module named Image - imported by kivy.core.image.img_pil (optional), docutils.writers._html_base (optional), docutils.writers.odf_odt (optional), docutils.parsers.rst.directives.images (optional)
    missing module named 'opencv.highgui' - imported by kivy.core.camera.camera_opencv (optional)
    missing module named opencv - imported by kivy.core.camera.camera_opencv (optional)
    missing module named picamera - imported by kivy.core.camera.camera_picamera (top-level)
    missing module named roman - imported by docutils.writers.latex2e (optional), docutils.writers.manpage (optional)
    missing module named elementtree - imported by docutils.writers.odf_odt (optional)
    missing module named 'android.runnable' - imported by kivy.core.clipboard.clipboard_android (top-level)
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following into your spec:

## Snippets - spec

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
from kivy.deps import sdl2, glew
. 
.
.
coll = COLLECT(exe, Tree('C:\\Users\\acer\\Desktop\\coding\\')
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='hello')
```

## Output

### Environment

- Windows 10 Home
- PyInstaller v3.4
- Python v3.7.2

[image: App running]

Comment: mine dist one is already working but not stand alone exe which is present inside `Build` dictionary

Comment: To bundle your app to a stand alone exe or one file, use `python -m PyInstaller  --onefile --windowed  --name hello main.py`.